# How to use SetEnvIf with Request_URI when it is rewritten to index.php?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, setenvif

We have a drupal website `a.com` that is password protected. I want all `a.com/api/...` URIs not to be, though. So I've read about `SetEnvIf`:

```
AuthName "Stage"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile ~/.htpasswd
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*data_sheets.*\.pdf" noauth
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/api/.+" noauth
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_Method OPTIONS noauth
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=noauth
Satisfy Any
```

The `/api/foobar` URIs are still asking for a password though. Since it's a Drupal website, with the help of anubhava we figured it has to do with how the request is handled by index.php.

How to deal with that?

Edit

Adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=noauth]
```

right after

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

didnt help

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess here?

Comment: @anubhava I've actually created a folder just for testing but it didnt work. its a regular drupal 8 htaccess: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.4.4

Comment: So `/api/...` is being rewritten to `/index.php` somewhere in this .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava sure, but the auth module runs *before* the rewrite module does, as I learned. also, you cant read the query string in the setenv stuff, so at the moment I could set noauth via modrewrite the auth stuff is already over

Comment: There are 3 different modules in play here.. `mod_auth`, `mod_setenv` and `mod_rewrite`. Ordering of those modules may be an issue here

Comment: @anubhava i thought the same, yup

Comment: I have just tried this snippet in my Apache 2.4 and it worked fine and didn't ask for auth while visiting `/api/foobar/`

Comment: @anubhava youre right, removing all the other htaccess stuff is giving me a not found. i guess ill have to change the question then

Comment: Instead of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/ [NC]` can you try `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /api/ [NC]`

Comment: @anubhava no luck :/

Comment: Problem is that I can't reproduce this problem on my Apache.

Comment: @anubhava i see. it must have to do something with the rest of the drupal htaccess, which i cant just remove, so there must be a solution. i wont be able to find it myself, though, probably :(

Comment: You’ll want to use `FallbackResource /index.php` instead of using mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
AuthName "Stage"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*data_sheets.*\.pdf" noauth
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/api/.+" noauth
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_Method OPTIONS noauth

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/api/
RewriteRule ^ - [E=noauth:1]

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=noauth
Allow from env=rewritten
Satisfy Any

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: is `\s` making sense? isnt this a blank?

Comment: `THE_REQUEST` contains the full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g., `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`), therefore the blank before `/api/`

Comment: Also note that `%{THE_REQUEST}` will, in case there are internal rewrites, preserve the value of initial request (which is not the case for `%{REQUEST_URI}`)

Answer (score 2):

I’m two years late but I’ve worked out a [thorough explanation](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/httpd-subrequest-variable-inconsistencies.html) of what’s going on and how you can work around it. The short version:

RewriteRule is fulfilled by a subrequest. The SetEnvIf module doesn’t inherit the REQUEST_URI variable in subrequests. Your noauth variable ends up as undefined in these subrequests.

Use `<Location>` and `<LocationMatch>` blocks together with mod_core’s `SetEnv` instead of relying on mod_setenvif.

Answer (score 1):

I am visiting this question after 3 years for some reason and attempting to post a working solution that should work in any Apache version.

You may try these rules in your site root .htaccess with Drupal rules:

```sh
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

# remove /index.php from URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# allow anything that starts with /api/
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/api/ noauth

<FilesMatch "^(?!index\.php$).*$">
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Stage"
   AuthUserFile ~/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user
   Order   Deny,Allow
   Deny from  all
   Allow from env=noauth
   Satisfy any
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, the question is so old though I dont even remember the project ;)

Comment: yes I know it was old but problem remained unanswered so I thought I would post a working answer to help future visitors to your question