# Disable htaccess auth for rewritten path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, setenvif

I have the following .htaccess file with basic auth and URL rewriting. I need to disable basic auth for a specific path (e.g., '/openaccess'), yet the rewriting happens first, so I can't disable the auth with SetEnvIf. The closest thing I've found is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48889419), but it doesn't work for me on Apache 2.4.34.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd

SetEnvIf Request_URI /openaccess  noauth=1

<RequireAny>
  Require env noauth
  Require env REDIRECT_noauth
  Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```